# call a function of a maincontroller after a presented viewcontroller is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a MainViewcontroller that present a viewcontroller. The user may take an action that should firstly dismiss the view controller and secondly call a function defined in the MainViewcontroller.

The constraint is this function will create a new vc to be presented. I have tried the viewWillAppear and viewdidAppear of the main controller. That did not work because they are called more than once.

I could also use the notification mechanism but I am not sure that the MainViewController will have appeared before the notification is received.

Comment: Use a boolean to detect whether you should call that function and set it false after the first run of `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [presentingViewController document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller). From presented view controller, you can get MainViewController by using `self.presentingViewController`. Try my code below

```
let mainViewController = self.presentingViewController as! MainViewController

self.dismiss(animated: true) {
  mainViewController.doWhateverYouWant()
}
```

Comment: By doing this, are you sure that the mainViewController is visible when the closure is executed ?

Comment: Closure will be executed after the view controller is dismissed. At this time, mainViewController is visible. You can try it.

Comment: your code throws an unexpectedly nil while unwrappin an optional

Comment: Updated my answer, you can try it again.

Comment: I think that the mainviewcontroller should be defined outside the closure to be captured.

Answer (score 1):

### Specific Solution

Let's say this is your `MainViewController`

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    func foo() {
        print("foo")
    }    
}
```

You can declare your `SecondViewController` like this

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func didTapDismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let mainViewController = self.presentingViewController as? MainViewController
        super.dismiss(animated: flag) {
            mainViewController?.foo()
            completion?()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see as soon as `SecondViewController` is dismissed, the `mainViewController?.foo()` method is invoked.

### General Solution

Let's define `MainViewController`

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    typealias CallBack = () -> Void

    func foo() {
        print("foo")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let mainViewControllerCallbackProtocol = segue.destination as? MainViewControllerCallbackProtocol {
            mainViewControllerCallbackProtocol.mainViewControllerCallback = { [weak self] in
                self?.foo()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And its own Callback protocol

```
protocol MainViewControllerCallbackProtocol:AnyObject {
    var mainViewControllerCallback: MainViewController.CallBack? { get set }
}
```

Finally let's conform `SecondViewController` to `MainViewControllerCallbackProtocol`

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MainViewControllerCallbackProtocol {

    var mainViewControllerCallback: MainViewController.CallBack?

    @IBAction func didTapDismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag) { [weak self] in
            self?.mainViewControllerCallback?()
            completion?()
        }
    }
}
```